# 1999 Toyota Corolla 4EFE 1.3 litre whining noise - louder with increasing speed

Tags: toyota, noise, manual-transmission, corolla

I have a 1999 Toyota Corolla 1.3l 4EFE engine. 138000 miles. 5 speed manual gearbox.

There is a whine/noise that gets louder the faster I drive. It is the same in any gear, and in neutral, and with the clutch in or out. It is not a wheel bearing noise - they are all fine.

I'm thinking its a bearing in the gearbox, or on a shaft somewhere.

Before I attempt to replace with a used gearbox, can anyone help identify the problem from these symptoms?

Its been getting progressively louder over the past 5000 miles. Any ideas how loud it could get before catastrophic failure?! Any indicators before completely gearbox lock out? Would a locked up gearbox damage the engine - can quick application of clutch stop damage?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked the gearbox oil?

Comment: How have you verified it's not a wheel bearing?

Comment: I’ve seen videos where a mechanic used a stethoscope to listen to every bearing in the drivetrain with car on hoist. Even at hand turn speed, rough bearings are noticeable. Perhaps that can work for you?

Comment: Does it change when you press the accelerator? Or drive downhill? How does it sound when you do curves on a highway (left and right)?

Comment: @HandyHowie Yeah gearbox oil went in 5 years and 50000 miles ago, still seemed clean ish and full.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Jacked up and searched for play in each wheel/ spinning wheels listening for dodgy bearing. The noise certainly seems to be coming from beneath the front of the car.

Comment: @Martin It doesn't differ based on accelerator use (apart from gradually as speed increases). Heavy and rapid accelerator usage doesn't change the noise heavily or rapidly...

Haven't tried specifically down a big hill but I've never noticed it go away if going downhill fast or anything. Will try again tomorrow.

I did not the other day that steering left or right DID change the tone of the whine ever so slightly

Comment: It makes no difference downhill either.

Comment: For sake of completeness: it was a wheel bearing in the end! I suppose I did not spin the wheel fast enough when checking to really hear the noise!